# Why my anchor points didn't connect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

So i created two curves and i saw 'intersect' and snapped to it.
After that i saw an error message about 'to join, you must select two open endpoints' when i was trying to join the two lines using ctrl-shift-alt-j (IDK what this is but it's part of tutorial).

Upon closer inspection and zooming 6400% i noticed the two path ending anchors aren't connected and i can't drag them onto each other to connect.

Why did this happen and why won't my path ending anchor points connect..?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did not select the anchor points.

Press A (selection tool) and choose two anchor points (square around them with clicked selection tool). Then right click and choose Join (you can try average and then Join as well).

Comment: Thanks! Wow, you have no idea how many hours i spent going through options and features .. i'm an idiot lol.

Comment: @Hyrule It is just basic stuff. Sometimes, it is more efficient just to ask and get an answer....